# How to get data from other component in angular 2?

Tags: angular2-services, angular2-directives

I have 2 separated components CityComponent and DistrictComponent. in CityComponent I have list of cities, how could I do to get data of cities in DistrictComponent to use *ngFor as select tag?

Answer (score 0):

you can use @input for such handling.

Assuming the distinct component have some key to filter out cities from city component.

you can refer below :

Step-1 :

district  component binding  as :

```
<district-component-selector [cityListInput]="cityList"></district-component-selector>
```

where, 
cityList holds complete list of cities in Component.

Step-2 :

In district component , you can refer it as :

```
import { Input } from "@angular/core";
@Input() set cityListInput(value: String[]) {
this.cityList= value;
}
```

where ,
cityList is your local variable in district component.